# Comparing datetime to a time range

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime object representing when a user logged, from this object I want to check whether the datetime object expresses a date in the range today -7, so if today is 2018-06-21 I would like to return ever date between today and 2018-06-14. I attach an example of my code (terribly wrong).

```
 def joined_today(self, query):

    filtered = []
    today = datetime.today().date()
    for x in query:
        if x[1].date() = today -7:
            filtered.append(x)

    return filtered
```

Comment: Did you mean to check if x[1] is within the last 7 days or if its date is exactly 7 days ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here. Firstly, you can do date calculations using `datetime.timedelta`.  And secondly, you don't want to check that the date is equal to "today - 7", you want to check it is greater than that and less than or equal to today. So:

```
seven_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=7)
for x in query:
    if seven_days_ago < x[1].date() <= today:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm just having this error now: `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'`

Comment: Ah, you've imported the datetime class not the module. Import timedelta from the same place - `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` and just reference it directly as updated above.